# G streamer Video Streaming and Receiving

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I need to receive a video in laptop from a Camera device which is connected to Video frame grabber(supports G-streamer). In laptop I need to process the video using opencv and then stream the video in RTSP format. How to receive a video and then stream the video in RTSP using G-streamer c++? Kindly share the example codes

[image]

This is my code sender.cpp is in laptop #1 and receiver.cpp code is in laptop #2. I can't able to see the video in receiver end. Additionally, attached my build information for your reference

**Sender.cpp**

```
cv::VideoCapture video;
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoWriter videoOut;
videoOut.open("appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,farmerate=30/1 ! jpegnc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.200 port=5000", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, 0 , 30, cv::Size(640,480),true);
if(video.open(0)) {
    while(video.isOpened()) {
        video >> frame;
        cv::putText(frame, "Processed Video", cv::Point(100,80),cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
        if(videoOut.isOpened())
            videoOut.write(frame);
        else
            cout<<"Writer Not Opened";
        cv::imshow("Sender", frame);
        cv::waitKey(25);
    }
}
else {
    cout<<"Camera Not Opened";
}
```

**Receiver.cpp**

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG, payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync = true async = true", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
 if(cap.isOpened()) {
     cv::Mat m;
     cout<<"Video Init";
     while(1) {
         cout<<"Video Streaming";
         cap >> m;
         cv::imshow("Receiver", m);
         cv::waitKey(10);
     }
 }
 else
     cout<<"Cap Not Opening";
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to capture the video data from the camera and use it in opencv using gstreamer?

Comment: Yes, and after using in opencv the processed video is to be streamed in RTSP format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the video using gstreamer, make sure you build opencv with GStreamer. Once you do that, simply create the pipeline for GStreamer and pass it as an argument to the `cv::VideoCapture()` object like so

```
std::string videoAddress = "udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync = true async = true";
cv::VideoCapture *camera = new cv::VideoCapture();
cameraOpened = camera->open(videoAddress, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

I'm not sure how to help with the second part of your question.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I tried the above code but I cant able to see the video, there is no error while running the code. I edited my questions with the code I tried, Can you please help me where I'm wrong

Comment: Use an application like Wireshark [https://www.wireshark.org/#download] to analyze the network traffic. This will tell you if the data you are sending has indeed been broadcasted and to check more details about that data, like what protocol is used for that data.

Comment: I can't see any data in wireshark(Receiver side). I think sender part itself has some bug.

Comment: @paulrajJ I'm glad you could trace the problem. I'm not certain how to help except by pointing you to Gstreamer's documentation on building a pipeline for streaming output.

Comment: Hello Shawn, I can able to see the data broadcasted in network using wireshark. In receiver side I'm getting distorted video and getting a warning "Redistribute latency and not enough buffering available for the processing deadline, add enough queues to buffer". Any ways to improve the buffer?

Comment: I tried 'queue max-size-bytes=900000 max-size-buffer=0 max-size-time=0' but no luck.

Comment: @paulrajJ Perhaps this should be a separate question so you can have more experienced people in Gstreamer helping you.